# How do I pull in rt.jar through maven?

Tags: maven, java

I'm trying to build a Java 5 system using Java 6. I have configured  and  with 1.5, but I also need to set  to point at a Java 5 rt.jar to ensure there are no faulty linkages like using Java 6 APIs. Has anyone ever configured maven to somehow pull rt.jar from a repository and reference it this way?

Answer (score 1):

You can verify your usage of external libraries - and implicitly of the Java core APIs - by using the [Animal Sniffer Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/)

> The Animal Sniffer Plugin is used to build signatures of APIs and to check your classes against previously generated signatures.

The plugin website shows how to [generate signatures for the Java runtime](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/examples/generating-java-signatures.html) and how to [check against generated signatures](http://www.mojohaus.org/animal-sniffer/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/examples/checking-signatures.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can send the source and target options down to javac by configuring the default maven java compiler plugin.  Take a look at [this page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) for an example.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but it doesn't prevent you from using Java 6 APIs. it only ensures you aren't using Java 6 language constructs. I'm talking about wiring in rt.jar as well. It appears that answer may be http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/rt/1.5.0_06 and http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Compile+and+Test+with+Different+JDK+Versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, it appears that only a pom file is located there. I can't find any jars.