# Using maven / ivy repository to get java rt.jar

Tags: java, maven, ivy

JDKs get installed in different places on different machines, I want to be able to support building with Java 7 targeting a Java 6 runtime.

I can specify -source 1.6 -target 1.6 to tell javac to target that runtime environment.
I can specify a -Xbootclasspath to tell it use a specific runtime jar

However Java 7 doesn't install java 6 runtime jars (not surprisingly).

When I look in the maven repository it just seems to have just up to 1.5:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun/rt

Has the group id changed in 1.6? Is it available via a maven / ivy dependency?

Comment: This is the same situation as asked about in 2011 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651250/how-do-i-pull-in-rt-jar-through-maven , except that was about 1.5. Sadly, it seems nobody has solved this issue still. Just having the rt.jar available in maven repos would be very neat indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add artifacts to a local maven repository (f.e. nexus or artifactory) and declare a dependency on that in your pom.

On the other hand: If you have a jdk installed you have already all classes in place to build for lower level runtimes, so there should be no need for the approach you described.

Comment: I'm wanting people to clone from github then build which is why I want to rely on an external maven repository.